# Statement about least significant bits in the next field of a linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, bit-manipulation

I found the following statement about the least significant bits in the next field of a linked list in C:

> "In C, the next field is a pointer. For performance reason related to memory subsystem on a processor, memory is allocated on word boundaries, and (at least) two least significant bits in the next pointers are 0."

Is this true? I can't understand why so if so. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many processor architectures are designed so that operations are supposed to be performed on word-aligned addresses.  For example, some 32-bit processors are designed so that any word operation must be done at addresses that are multiples of 4 bytes (32 bits), such as addresses 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, etc.  Similarly, some 64-bit processors only allow word operations to be done at addresses that are multiples of 8 bytes.  This has various advantages in hardware, such as being able to more easily detect if two different instructions refer to the same word in memory, which makes the processor faster.  In some processors, you'll get a bus error if you try to do a nonaligned read, while in others it's legal to do so but the performance will be significantly degraded.

Because of this, most memory allocation libraries are designed so that they align all allocations at word boundaries.  This means that on a 32-bit system, the two low-order bits of the address will be 0 (because the number is a multiple of four) and on a 64-bit system the three low-order bits of the address will be 0.  Many data structures compress their representations by using these low-order bits to store extra information.  For example, some implementations of red/black trees will place the bit that stores whether a node is red or black into the low order bits of one of the pointers, and some AVL trees (which need to store two bits of information) will pack those bits into the low-order bits of these pointers.  Some garbage collection algorithms use similar techniques to store mark bits.

**EDIT**: In C, some compilers support a `uintptr_t` type that represents an integer large enough to hold a pointer.  You can cast the pointer to a `uintptr_t` and then use standard bitwise operators on the `uintptr_t` variable to set or clear the bits, then cast back to a pointer to store the result.  In C++, to the best of my knowledge, this would produce undefined behavior.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a much more in depth explanation than mine, I tried to keep mine as a higher-level explanation. Nice job!

Comment: It's more than just the allocation library.  The compiler must also choose to align all data on the stack on 4-byte boundaries.  Gcc still has a `-mno-stack-align` option for some embedded processors, for example.

Comment: @Gene: Platforms with stack requirement alignments typically require that the **stack pointer** be aligned, either all the time or only at routine entry/exit. They generally do not require that **objects on the stack** be aligned. E.g., a compiler is free to allocate 32 bytes on the stack but then put a `char` at offset 5, a two-byte `short` at offset 14, and so on.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Regarding the use of low bits in C. There is now some standardization of this. If an implementation supports `uintptr_t` and presents the address in it in the normal way, then a program can convert a pointer to `uintptr_t`, fiddle with the low two bits, store it away for later, retrieve it, separate out the low two bits and clear them, and convert back to a pointer, and the result serves as the original pointer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil- Thanks for the info!  I didn't know that, and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks. Certainly that's understood. Sorry if I was not clear. My point was that to assume the low bits of pointers are zero as the OP says, all pointers must play by the rules. This means that items on the stack must lie on 4-byte boundaries as well as those allocated on the heap with the allocation library. The compiler must implement this policy. If the compiler might align e.g. 2-byte or 1-byte data arbitrarily, then you can't used data items of these sizes. I've seen various systems use the last 2 bits of pointers for type tags in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you request a block of memory it is delivered to you in a block that is aligned with the [word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29) of the architecture, in others words it will be starting from a memory address that is a multiple of the word. If it is on a multiple of the word it is an even number, ruling out the first least significant bit to be on. On a 32-bit machine the word size chunk will be 4, and 4 in binary is 100, hence the second least significant bit is turned off.

Here is an example of what I mean by alignment with the word. Consider the following structure (assuming 32-bit):

```
struct sample {
  char a;
  int b;
  char c;
  char d;
};
```

... requires 8 bytes, not 7 (due to [data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)).

**Remark:** Compilers must adhere to this, however it is **not required**. Most do, or have the option to.

Comment: The optimal and/or required alignments for an object are not necessarily the general word size of a machine and may even be different for different kinds of objects on the same machine.